# google test in fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rostest, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the recommended best way to integrate Google Test with fuerte/rosmake? I've looked at the wiki pages for gtest, rostest and rosunit, but I'm not sure which is the most up to date/best to use. Also, is there a good tutorial on how to set everything up and write a unit test in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65352/google-test-in-fuerte/) by [somudrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/2500/somudrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general you should right unit tests using gtest directly.  You will then just need to register them as unit tests with the buildsystem ([rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists#Test_macros) or [catkin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Unit_Tests))

[rosunit](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosunit) is a test runner which we use in the continuous integration process, but it requires gtest compatible unit tests.  As a developer you can use it to run your tests, but it's not part of how you consider running your unit tests.

[rostest](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostest) is how you can write tests which run multiple processes and test ROS based communications.  Within a rostest you should have a gtest node which is doing asserts, and other modules to fill out the other side of the communications.  There's good focused tutorials for rostest on it's homepage.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1